# Is there a way to change Xcode's behaviour of protocol conformance autocompletion

Tags: xcode

Lets say I have protocol:

```
protocol FooProtocol{
    func bar<Request: Codable, Response: Codable>()
}
```

And I have class:

```
class Foo: FooProtocol { //Xcode complains here about protocol conformance with a fix button
}
```

if I tap on the Xcode autocomplete to fix the protocol conformance, the following function is generated:

```
class Foo: FooProtocol {
    func bar<Request, Response>() where Request : Decodable, Request : Encodable, Response : Decodable, Response : Encodable {

    }
}
```

Not very pretty. I have to manually rewrite the function:

```
func bar<Request: Codable, Response: Codable>()
```

is there a way to change this behaviour in Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. And all of the standard library is formatted in that heinous way too.

```swift
struct Dictionary<Key, Value> where Key : Hashable {
```

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/combinelatest4
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2884879-init